# Windows Explorer Detailed View Column Width Registry/Policy Setting

Tags: windows, view, directory

When a folder in Windows is set to Details view, it should different information for each column. You can adjust the width of the column by dragging them or right clicking and select more. But that only applies it to that folder. I was wondering if there are any registry setting or policy setting that can change the default setting of the width for all folders?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for Windows 7, similar methods work on prior versions too.

- Open an explorer window.
- Choose the view settings you desire to apply to all windows.
- Click the **Tools | Folder options** menu item.
- Select the **View** page.
- Click on **Apply to folders**.

This will apply the current window's settings to all other folders with the same type of content.

Comment: this sometimes will have weird effects. I tried that once and it changed all my folders to Details view, including the ones I don't want in Details view.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what it is supposed to do. That's what it says it does.

Comment: no, you stated settings applied to folder with same type of content, but it applies to all folders regardless of contents.

Comment: Not true. Right click on a folder. Move to the Customize page. See the drop down in the *What kind of folder do you want?* group box? That determines the type of content. The *Apply to folders* action only applies the settings to those folders with the same content type as the window from which you opened the Folder options dialog.

Comment: But it is possible to have folders in the General category with multiple views settings. Like my folders for example, most of my folders are default to General, but some have Large Icon view and some have Details view.

Comment: Individual folders maintain their own settings. Clicking *Apply to folders* sets all those settings to be the same as the active window. You can then customise individual settings beyond that.

Comment: True, but I am just looking for a way to adjust one particular setting for one group of folder. Base on your recommendation, I have to reset all my folder and readjust all of that...

Comment: Read your question again, especially the part which says "all folders".

Comment: The question says only the column "width for all folders". Also, the question asks if there were any registry or policy settings...